# java.util.List.iterator() is no accessor method

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I am trying to access, List method `iterator()` i am getting below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator() is no accessor method!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.MapAccessingMethodInterceptor$Accessor.<init>(MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:218) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Code snippet below:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/{field}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public void applyPatchRequest(@PathVariable String field ,JsonArray operations) {  
    LookupPatchDto lookupPatchDto = new LookupPatchDto();
    lookupPatchDto.setField(field);
    lookupPatchDto.setVals(lookupValsService.getAllByField(field));
    final JsonPatch patch = Json.createPatch(operations);
    final JsonObject result = patch.apply(lookupPatchConverter.toJson(lookupPatchDto));
    lookupPatchDto  = lookupPatchConverter.fromJson(result);
    lookupValsService.save(lookupPatchDto.getVals());
}
```

I am getting error on below line while applying apply function.

```
final JsonObject result = patch.apply(lookupPatchConverter.toJson(lookupPatchDto));
```

Comment: Can you please post your code to figure out where you getting this exception.

Comment: Did you configure the iterator() method at a place where Spring would expect a getXxx() method? Or did you use "iterator" as a property name in your configuration?

Comment: Can you try and split the suspicious line into two? First convert toJson, then apply so that it will be clear which operation causes the issue? Also, what is the type of this lookupPatchConverter?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.The problem is resolved now.
I was passing an object "operations" of JsonArray which was empty to 
Json.createPatch(operations) method which then returned an instance of JsonPatch having one of the instance variable of JsonArray type as empty.
when i was trying to use apply method.It internally tries to iterate using that JsonArray object which it finds empty and throws no accessor error.